# How to append laravel code in jquery to copy div?

Tags: laravel, append, clone

> I am working on laravel form. Form contains 2 div.  1st div contains
>   company personal info. 2nd div contains company address. one comapny
>   will have multiple address. so i want onclick button `companyaddress`
>   div should be clone. I was refered one code but that's working code.
>   but in my case its not working because i am using blade so i dont
>   undestand how to append my code into javascript.

**For reference i am using this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q8zj00s0/1/**

**i am sharing my code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('address',trans('messages.address'),[])!!}
    {!! Form::input('text','address_line_1',(isset($company) ? $company->address_line_1 : ''),['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.address_line_1')])!!}
                    <br />
    {!! Form::input('text','address_line_2',(isset($company) ? $company->address_line_2 : ''),['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.address_line_2')])!!}
                    <br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      {!! Form::input('text','city',(isset($company) ? $company->city : ''),['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.city')])!!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      {!! Form::input('text','state',(isset($company) ? $company->state : ''),['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.state')])!!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      {!! Form::input('text','zipcode',(isset($company) ? $company->zipcode : ''),['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.zipcode')])!!}
    </div>
    </div>
                    <br />
      {!! Form::select('country_id', config('country'),(isset($company) ? $company->country_id : ''),['class'=>'form-control show-tick','title'=>trans('messages.country')])!!}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your jQuery code?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Name' /></li>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='phone[]' placeholder='Phone' /></li>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='email[]' placeholder='E-Mail' /></li>");
  });
});

</script>` in place of `<li>` i want to use my laravel code

Comment: In your HTML, ul with fieldList id is missing. You'll have to use same HTML structure if you are copying the jquery from that fiddle.

Comment: I don't see any problem if your using the blade template .
The problem must be in your js code .

check if your js file is included and if your id or classes are correct

Goodluck